# Get Contentful entry by ID and locale

Tags: javascript, contentful

The Contentful npm package provide access to all the functionality from the API. In my case, I know the ID for the entry I want, but need to retrieve the data for a non-default locale and I can't see any way to pass the locale option. My query looks like this:

```
const { createClient } = require('contentful');

const contentfulClient = createClient({
  accessToken: 'xxxxxxxx',
  space: 'xxxxxxx',
});

const entry = contentfulClient
  .getEntry('xxxxxx')
  .catch(console.error);
```

I know I could do the following:

```
const data = await contentfulClient
  .getEntries({
    content_type: 'xxxxxx'
    locale: 'cy',
    'sys.id': xxxxx,
  })
  .catch(console.error);

const [entry] = data.items;
```

But this requires the content type and returns an array of entries, which seems counter intuitive when I know the exact entry I want. Am I missing something? Seems like a logical thing to expect it to do.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It doesn't say so on the [API documentation](https://www.contentful.com/developers/docs/references/content-delivery-api/#/reference/entries/entry/get-a-single-entry/console) but you can absolutely use the `locale=` parameter via the API.

```
▶ curl -H "Authorization: Bearer $CONTENTFUL_ACCESS_TOKEN" https://cdn.contentful.com/spaces/$CONTENTFUL_SPACE_ID/entries/6wU8cSKG9UOE0sIy8Sk20G
{
  "sys": {
    "space": {
      "sys": {
        "type": "Link",
        "linkType": "Space",
        "id": "xxxx"
      }
    },
    "id": "6wU8cSKG9UOE0sIy8Sk20G",
    "type": "Entry",
    "createdAt": "2018-09-06T22:01:55.103Z",
    "updatedAt": "2018-10-08T19:26:59.382Z",
    "environment": {
      "sys": {
        "id": "master",
        "type": "Link",
        "linkType": "Environment"
      }
    },
    "revision": 14,
    "contentType": {
      "sys": {
        "type": "Link",
        "linkType": "ContentType",
        "id": "section"
      }
    },
    "locale": "en-US"
  },
  "fields": {
    "internalTitle": "test test test",
    ...

▶ curl -H "Authorization: Bearer $CONTENTFUL_ACCESS_TOKEN" https://cdn.contentful.com/spaces/$CONTENTFUL_SPACE_ID/entries/6wU8cSKG9UOE0sIy8Sk20G\?locale\=\*
{
  "sys": {
    "space": {
      "sys": {
        "type": "Link",
        "linkType": "Space",
        "id": "xxxx"
      }
    },
    "id": "6wU8cSKG9UOE0sIy8Sk20G",
    "type": "Entry",
    "createdAt": "2018-09-06T22:01:55.103Z",
    "updatedAt": "2018-10-08T19:26:59.382Z",
    "environment": {
      "sys": {
        "id": "master",
        "type": "Link",
        "linkType": "Environment"
      }
    },
    "revision": 14,
    "contentType": {
      "sys": {
        "type": "Link",
        "linkType": "ContentType",
        "id": "section"
      }
    }
  },
  "fields": {
    "internalTitle": {
      "en-US": "test test test"
    },
    ...
```

The [documentation for the contentful JS client](https://contentful.github.io/contentful.js/contentful/7.1.0/ContentfulClientAPI.html#.getEntry) says:

> Parameters:
>   Name  Type    Attributes  Description. 
>   id    string
>   query     Object  optional.
>     Object with search parameters. In this method it's only useful for `locale`.

so you'd add the locale as the second parameter to `getEntry` like so:

```
const entry = contentfulClient
  .getEntry('xxxxxx', { locale: 'en-US' })
```